# How to explode column with csv string in PySpark?

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like this

```
+---+---------------------+
| id|                  csv|
+---+---------------------+
|  1|a,b,c\n1,2,3\n2,3,4\n|
|  2|a,b,c\n3,4,5\n4,5,6\n|
|  3|a,b,c\n5,6,7\n6,7,8\n|
+---+---------------------+
```

and I want to explode the string type `csv` column, in fact I'm only interested in this column. So I'm looking for a method to obtain the following dataframe from the above.

```
+--+--+--+
| a| b| c|
+--+--+--+
| 1| 2| 3|
| 2| 3| 4|
| 3| 4| 5|
| 4| 5| 6|
| 5| 6| 7|
| 6| 7| 8|
+--+--+--+
```

Looking at the `from_csv` [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_csv.html) it seems that the insput csv string can contain only one row of data, which I found stated more clearly [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions/from_csv#arguments). So that's not an option.

I guess I could loop over the individual rows of the input dataframe, extract and parse the csv string from each row and then stitch everything together:

```
rows = df.collect()

for (i, row) in enumerate(rows):
  data = row['csv']
  data = data.split('\\n')
  rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)

  df_row = (spark.read
    .option('header', 'true')
    .schema('a int, b int, c int')
    .csv(rdd))

  if i == 0:
    df_new = df_row
  else:
    df_new = df_new.union(df_row)

df_new.show()
```

But that seems awfully inefficient. Is there a better way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `split` + `from_csv` functions along with `transform` you can do something like:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, r"a,b,c\n1,2,3\n2,3,4\n"), (2, r"a,b,c\n3,4,5\n4,5,6\n"),
    (3, r"a,b,c\n5,6,7\n6,7,8\n")], ["id", "csv"]
)

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "csv",
    F.transform(
        F.split(F.regexp_replace("csv", r"^a,b,c\\n|\\n$", ""), r"\\n"),
        lambda x: F.from_csv(x, "a int, b int, c int")
    )
).selectExpr("inline(csv)")

df1.show()

# +---+---+---+
# |  a|  b|  c|
# +---+---+---+
# |  1|  2|  3|
# |  2|  3|  4|
# |  3|  4|  5|
# |  4|  5|  6|
# |  5|  6|  7|
# |  6|  7|  8|
# +---+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! I'm new to PySpark so that was probably a dummy question...